# Minecraft Crashing when pressing play Have reinstalled multiple times. Version 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My Minecraft crashes when pressing play. Intel core i7 processor, Iris pro Graphics, Nvidia Geforce GTX 960m. The error message I receive is

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff89f54628c, pid=7936, tid=9840
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x55628c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7936.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: I'd recommend including the actual error report, it says it's saved in `C:\Users\nitin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7936.log`.

Comment: I had same problem, see solution below. after reinstalling java minecraft ran fine.

Comment: Do you use original client? Because those errors are often caused by non-original clients.

Comment: The linked question should solve the issue, but as a side-note: Your Minecraft doesn't seem to utilize your GTX 960m at all, considering the crash lies within your Intel graphics driver. Setting Minecraft to use your NVidia card might also solve your issues.

Answer (score -1):

It had happened to me twice.
At first I had Java-32 bit, I installed the minecraft 1.9 and everything was fine.
but at starting the actual game either survival or creative it displays message upgrade your Java to 64 bit for performance*. I had a10-6800k so i upgraded the java now the launcher crashes and gives this message
[image]

**SOLUTION**

I cleanly uninstalled java (all versions) and installed **32 bit** Java 8 update 91 and minecraft runs fine.

> NOTE:- On 64 bit Java Minecraft crashed and on 32 bit Java it ran fine. but I don't know the reason why

*see the image below

[image]

Comment: It is bad practise to use 32bit when 64bit is possible. This is bad solution.

Comment: Your error is not the same as the askers at all. A different "*Problematic Frame*" makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: So does this problem vary from machine to machine?